# How do I update the column without returnung more then 1 row or without using a join of the table I want to update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data from one column to another. The columns I want to update is Hrstotal and Empcnt.

```
+--------+----------------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+---------+----------+--------+
| projno | projname             | deptno | respemp | prstdate   | prendate   | majproj | Hrstotal | Empcnt |
+--------+----------------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+---------+----------+--------+
| AD3100 | Admin Services       | D01    | 000010  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | NULL    |     NULL |      0 |
| AD3110 | General AD Systems   | D21    | 000070  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | AD3100  |     NULL |      0 |
| AD3111 | Payroll Programming  | D21    | 000230  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | AD3110  |     NULL |      0 |
| AD3112 | Personnel Programmg  | D21    | 000250  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | AD3110  |     NULL |      0 |
| AD3113 | Account.Programming  | D21    | 000270  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | AD3110  |     NULL |      0 |
| IF1000 | Query Services       | C01    | 000030  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | NULL    |     NULL |      0 |
| IF2000 | User Education       | C01    | 000030  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | NULL    |     NULL |      0 |
| MA2100 | Weld Line Automation | D01    | 000010  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | NULL    |     NULL |      0 |
| MA2110 | W L Programming      | D11    | 000060  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | MA2100  |     NULL |      0 |
| MA2111 | W L Program Design   | D11    | 000220  | 2014-01-01 | 2014-12-01 | MA2110  |     NULL |      0 |
| MA2112 | W L Robot Design     | D11    | 000150  | 2014-01-01 | 2014-12-01 | MA2110  |     NULL |      0 |
| MA2113 | W L Prod Cont Progs  | D11    | 000160  | 2014-02-15 | 2014-12-01 | MA2110  |     NULL |      0 |
| OP1000 | Operation Support    | E01    | 000050  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | NULL    |     NULL |      0 |
| OP1010 | Operation            | E11    | 000090  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | OP1000  |     NULL |      0 |
| OP2000 | GEN Systems Services | E01    | 000050  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | OP1000  |     NULL |      0 |
| OP2010 | Systems Support      | E21    | 000100  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | OP2000  |     NULL |      0 |
| OP2011 | SCP Systems Support  | E21    | 000320  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | OP2010  |     NULL |      0 |
| OP2012 | Applications Support | E21    | 000330  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | OP2010  |     NULL |      0 |
| OP2013 | DB/DC Support        | E21    | 000340  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | OP2010  |     NULL |      0 |
| PL2100 | Weld Line Planning   | B01    | 000020  | 2014-01-01 | 2014-09-15 | MA2100  |     NULL |      0 |
+--------+----------------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+---------+----------+--------+
```

The values I want is Empcnt = for recording the number of employees working on each project and Hrstotal = for recording the total hours to be spent on each project by all the employees assigned to it. This data can be calculated from these table:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| empno  | projno | hours |
+--------+--------+-------+
| 000020 | PL2100 |    31 |
| 000030 | IF1000 |    11 |
| 000030 | IF2000 |    10 |
| 000050 | OP1000 |    16 |
| 000050 | OP2000 |    15 |
| 000060 | MA2110 |     8 |
| 000060 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000060 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000060 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000070 | AD3110 |     8 |
| 000070 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000070 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000070 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000090 | OP1010 |    31 |
| 000100 | OP2010 |     8 |
| 000100 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000100 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000100 | OP2013 |     7 |
| 000130 | IF1000 |    10 |
| 000130 | IF2000 |    10 |
| 000140 | IF1000 |    10 |
| 000140 | IF2000 |    10 |
| 000150 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000150 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000150 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000150 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000230 | AD3110 |     8 |
| 000230 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000230 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000230 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000280 | OP1010 |    31 |
| 000290 | OP1010 |    30 |
| 000300 | OP1010 |    30 |
| 000310 | OP1010 |    30 |
| 000320 | OP2010 |     8 |
| 000320 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000320 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000320 | OP2013 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2010 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2013 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2010 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2013 |     7 |
```

The queries I've been trying with each error

```
UPDATE Proj set Empcnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pworks GROUP BY empno);
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

mysql> UPDATE Proj p set Empcnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pworks WHERE projno = p.projno GROUP BY empno);
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

INSERT INTO Proj(Empcnt) SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM Pworks INNER JOIN Proj ON empno = respemp GROUP BY empno;
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'projno' doesn't have a default value

 UPDATE Proj SET Empcnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pworks NATURAL JOIN Proj GROUP BY Proj.projno);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'Proj' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Proj p
    SET Empcnt = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM Pworks pw
                  WHERE pw.projno = p.projno
------------------------^ this is the correlation clause that counts the employees on each project
                 )
```